# Set build parameter values at runtime with the Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, groovy, jenkins-pipeline

I'm using a private Github repo with a `Jenkinsfile` to build a project. I'd actually like to do two separate builds, one for `develop` that builds whenever a branch is pushed, and one for `qa` that builds nightly. I've set up a Github Organization as this seems to be the only way to use credentials to check out the repository and perform the build.

My Jenkinsfile looks like:

```
node {
    stage('Preparation') {
        properties([[$class: 'ParametersDefinitionProperty',
            parameterDefinitions: [
                [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', name: 'build_url'],
                [$class: 'StringParameterDefinition', name: 'build_url2'],
            ]
        ]])
        checkout scm
    }
    stage('Build') {
        dir('Vecna_iDeliver_Torso') {
            sh 'npm install'
            sh 'node_modules/.bin/gulp build'
        }
    }
    stage('Upload') {
        sh 'aws s3 sync dist s3://app-dev'
    }
    stage('Cleanup') {
        deleteDir()
    }
}
```

This all works great, but I need to be able to set the environment variables (build urls) when running `gulp`, and their values will depend on the environment I want to build for. The `s3` bucket I want to upload to will also depend on the environment.

When I set the `properties` above and then find the build job under my Github organization, I can see that it's accepting the build parameters. However, there doesn't seem to be any way for me to set these externally. I can only use them with "Build with Parameters." This would be fine if I wanted to run the build manually each time, but I want it to run nightly. Since the two different environments require different build parameter values, I can't set them as defaults.

Is there any way for me to set build parameter values ahead of time using the Jenkins pipeline?

Comment: Would you be ok with a separate Jenkinsfile for each build job? That should do the trick.

Comment: I think, it does not relate to pipeline. You can have a property file (or values from environment parameters) and use these values in gulpfile.js during build. In other words, just create a file with you settings per each host, and modify gulpfile scripts to use values from the file (or system env), and put the specific property file to the specific host .

Comment: @yvs, Im not sure that makes sense. Build jobs have separate definitions that are not changed before the job executes. Involving gulp means that we would change the values in the jenkinsfile before the pipeline executed?